# How to duplicate (copy) a CIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

How can I duplicate a CIImage from another CIImage without going through rendering a CGImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CIImage *copiedImage = [originalImage copy];
```

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `CIImage` conforms to `NSCopying`.

Comment: my bad, I was in the UIImage section in the Doc, indeed it conforms to  NSCopying (I was wondering why it would not) hehe thx!

Comment: @NicolasManzini The Xcode 5 built-in documentation no longer lists the protocols to which `CIImage` conforms right at the top of the document, like it used to, so I don't blame you for not noticing that it conforms to `NSCopying`. You have to click on the `ℹ` icon on the panel on the right.

Comment: lol I knew that but I didn't saw that typing CIImage in the doc searchbar was opening UIImage not CIImage... and btw the new presentation isn't that great..